# Perform segue with multiple states on a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

I have a UITableView that has two states. One when the user is logged in and the other is when the user is logged out. Both show different details filling up around 4 rows each. What I have at the moment does not work. How can I fix it or should I replace it with better code. Thanks

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                if  loggedIn.contains("Find Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Create Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Past Events"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutopast", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Recently Viewed"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutorv", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Help"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Setting"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutosetting", sender: nil)
                }
            }
            else {

                if  loggedOut.contains("Log In"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutologin", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Find Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Create Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Help"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
                } 

            }
        }
```

Comment: how are storing value to loggedIn variable ?. we need that code

Comment: "What I have at the moment does not work" why? there is a better approach to refactor this code, but I assume as a functionality it should work fine.

Comment: give more info about your issue.

Comment: @vinodh i am storing the variables like this
        var loggedIn = ["Find Event", "Create Event", "Past Events", "Recently Viewed", "Help", "Setting"]
        
        var loggedOut = ["Log In", "Find Event", "Create Event", "Help"]

Comment: 1.) Use switch

2.) Can you provide more information? Maybe consider redoing the thing with other component... 

3.) Use indexPath.row to differ cells...

Comment: @AhmadF When I go into the app and click on something it will always take me to the first view controller.

Comment: @Basheer When I click on the 3rd row it will take me to the 1st View Controller and not the 3rd View Controller.

Comment: look below and you will see the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding this correctly then you wish to trigger a specific segue depending on which cell you tap on. Your current code will not work because the your first `if` statement will always resolve as true, which is likely why you're only ever triggering the first segue.

A better approach would be use the `indexPath.row` of the current cell and select a segue based on that, this will cut down your code drastically. I would also suggest creating a `struct` so you can store more data and use it more effectively throughout your `tableView`.

I've made some changes to your code below, see if that helps.

```
struct UserCell {

    public let title: String
    public let segue: String

    init(title: String, segue: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.segue = segue
    }
}


class SideTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var loggout: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!

    private let loggedIn: [UserCell] = [
        UserCell(title: "Find Event", segue: "menutofind"),
        UserCell(title: "Create Event", segue: "menutocreate"),
        UserCell(title: "Past Events", segue: "menutopast"),
        UserCell(title: "Recently Viewed", segue: "menutorv"),
        UserCell(title: "Help", segue: "menutohelp"),
        UserCell(title: "Setting", segue: "menutosetting")
    ]

    private let loggedOut: [UserCell] = [
        UserCell(title: "Log In", segue: "menutologin"),
        UserCell(title: "Find Event", segue: "menutofind"),
        UserCell(title: "Create Event", segue: "menutocreate"),
        UserCell(title: "Help", segue: "menutohelp")
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius =
            dismissButton.frame.size.width / 2
        loggout.layer.cornerRadius =
            loggout.frame.size.width / 2
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            loggout.isHidden = false
            print("User Signed In, Showing Relivent Info")

        } else {
            loggout.isHidden = true
            print("User Not Logged In, Showing Relivent Info")
        }
        tableview.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // User is signed in.
            return loggedIn.count

        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            return loggedOut.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // User is signed in.
            cell.textLabel?.text = loggedIn[indexPath.item].title
            return cell

        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            cell.textLabel?.text = loggedOut[indexPath.item].title
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: self.loggedIn[indexPath.row].segue, sender: nil)
        }
        else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: self.loggedOut[indexPath.row].segue, sender: nil)
        }
}
```

The `UserCell` struct can easily be extended to store more data and make it easy to access this when you need it.

Comment: Thanks. This works, but when Im logged in and click on Create Event and Recently Viewed it crashes the app.

Comment: That might be a problem elsewhere in your code, make sure your segue identifiers are correct and that everything else is set up correctly. If you do find that it's something with the above code then let me know and I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem, in my case I used two arrays to store the options, so one you Will store the options that Will appear when the user is logged in and another you Will store options that Will appear if the user is  logged out.

Then I used **indexPath.row** to detect which position was chosen. don't forget to use an **if**, to detect if the user is logged or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is the full code

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

    class SideTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



        @IBOutlet weak var loggout: UIButton!
        @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!

        var loggedIn = ["Find Event", "Create Event", "Past Events", "Recently Viewed", "Help", "Setting"]

        var loggedOut = ["Log In", "Find Event", "Create Event", "Help"]


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius =
            dismissButton.frame.size.width / 2
            loggout.layer.cornerRadius =
            loggout.frame.size.width / 2
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                loggout.isHidden = false
                print("User Signed In, Showing Relivent Info")

            } else {
                loggout.isHidden = true
                print("User Not Logged In, Showing Relivent Info")
            }
            tableview.reloadData()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                return loggedIn.count

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                return loggedOut.count
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                // User is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedIn[indexPath.item]
                return cell

            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                cell.textLabel?.text = loggedOut[indexPath.item]
                return cell
            }
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                if  loggedIn.contains("Find Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Create Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Past Events"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutopast", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Recently Viewed"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutorv", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Help"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedIn.contains("Setting"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutosetting", sender: nil)
                }
            }
            else {

                if  loggedOut.contains("Log In"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutologin", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Find Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutofind", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Create Event"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutocreate", sender: nil)
                }
                else if  loggedOut.contains("Help"){
                    performSegue(withIdentifier: "menutohelp", sender: nil)
                } 

            }
        }
```